# Google photos api - Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: canvas, todataurl, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am building a design tool to create fully customizable photo products like photobooks. I use technologies such as firebase (database and storage) and angular4. In order to integrate google photos with my web app I use the google photos api. When I try to edit user's photos with html canvas (toDataUrl) I get the following error: 
**"Access to Image at '...' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."** 
I know what it means but i can't find any solution in order to edit user's photos and use them for printing purposes. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Check if Google API is blocking the calls from localhost or the domain you are hosting the tool

Comment: Aside from setting up your own proxy server did you come up with a solution?  Shutterfly requires Google Photos to be copied to their server before editing.  I think this might be the reason.

Comment: I have this same problem. I'm also using angular. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Same here, relevant feature request here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118662029

Comment: Having the same problem. Have you managed to find a solution?